# Get the related entry from an Entries field in a Matrix block within a plugin craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

So I've got this which accurately gives me the desired relation block within my matrix, but how do I actually get the Entry object from a relation field?

```
$project = Entry::find()->id($projectId)->one();

foreach ($project->location as $locations) {
        if ($locations->getType()->name === 'Locations') {
            // Grab a building from the block. 
            // Right now this just returns the relation table ID, I'd like the actual Entry object with it's attributes.
            $buildings = $locations->buildings;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey there - figured this one out on my own, so to get all of the related objects, I just needed to change the above query to `$buildings = $location->buildings->all();`

Comment: Would you mind adding that solution as an official answer, Brett?  Might end up helping someone in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

figured this one out on my own, so to get all of the related objects, I just needed to change the above query to `$buildings = $location->buildings->all();`