# Is there a way to get categories relating to a specific entry within a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

When I get an Entry Object that has been set, I notice all of my fields except the Category fields are available to me. For example:

```
[_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
    (
        [customFields] => craft\behaviors\ContentBehavior Object
            (
                [adjustedRemainingLife] => 100%
                [adjustedRemainingYears] => 116
                [answerSets] => [{"col3":"Paving and curbs are less than 3 years old, and in good condition. No repairs are needed, preventative maintenance ","col1":"Paving and curbs are in good condition, and only require routine maintenance - 90%","col2":"Minor repairs and patching are required, not exceeding 30% of value -\r\n60%","col4":"Significant repairs are needed to as much as 60% of value. - 30%","col5":"All or majority of systems should be replaced - 0%"}]
                [groundsQuestions] =>
```

Where `groundsQuestions` is my category field, I figure if it isn't flowing through, there must be some way to get that value in a plugin?

Comment: It is exactly the same behavior as you already figured out here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26326/get-the-related-entry-from-an-entries-field-in-a-matrix-block-within-a-plugin-cr

Comment: Lightbulb moment!  Thanks @RobinSchambach!

Answer (score 1):

Since `groundsQuestions` is a category field, calling it will return an element query on which you can call `one()`, `all()`, etc.

For example:

```
$groundsQuestions = $entry->groundsQuestions->all();
```